# Drupal Common's 3 How To Edit The Commons Browsing Widget Tabs?

Tags: 7

In Drupal 7 Common 3

Browsing Widget Tabs
https://drupal.org/project/commons_bw

Want to remove the Wiki's Tab
How can I do this please?

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: What about turning off "commons wiki" module?

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically need to remove the *Wiki's Tab* instead of turning off **Commons Wiki module**, none of the functions to override has been set up as a hook, as far as I can understand.

So even if the following method is not the best approach, you could make a very quick patch to commons_bw.module :

Into `function commons_bw_get_tab_definitions($widget_type = 'group')`

add `unset($tabs['commons_wikis']);` before `return $tabs;`

Of course you'll have to remember this whenever you update your Commons distrib...

See also this great post on [how to add your own content type to the **Commons browsing widget**](https://drupal.org/node/1782922). This will give you a complete overview of what you can do

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the tabs at this address [yoursite]/admin/config/user-interface/commons-browsing-widget-user-interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/commons_bw_ui. This module provides a user interface that allows you to disable, remove or add new tabs.

Commons Browsing Widget User Interface comes with a number of useful features:

- Greatly simplifies the process of adding, altering or removing
  browsing widget tabs.
- Provides configuration options for all tab
  settings including: title, weight, view, display and bundle.
- Allows the default browsing widget tab settings to be overridden.
- Automatically configures content types for proper integration with
  Commons (adds fields, enables title replacement, etc.).
- Configuration is fully exportable.